# Pair SQL records without Cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to pair records in a SQL table, my table looks similar to this:

```
UID      DATE          TIME      MateID
---------------------------------------
1        2013-06-07    08:00     NULL
2        2013-06-07    10:00     NULL
3        2013-06-07    13:00     NULL
4        2013-06-07    17:00     NULL
5        2013-06-08    07:00     NULL
6        2013-06-08    11:00     NULL
7        2013-06-08    14:00     NULL
8        2013-06-08    18:00     NULL
```

I know I can do this with a cursor, but I wanted to know if there was a set based solution that could give me this output:

```
UID      DATE          TIME      MateID
---------------------------------------
1        2013-06-07    08:00     2
2        2013-06-07    10:00     1
3        2013-06-07    13:00     4
4        2013-06-07    17:00     3
5        2013-06-08    07:00     6
6        2013-06-08    11:00     5
7        2013-06-08    14:00     8
8        2013-06-08    18:00     7
```

The UID field won't be consecutive, the records will be ordered by DATE and TIME. The table will contain about 50k records

Edit: Sorry I should have been a bit more clear. MateID is the UID of the previous/next record. Records are grouped based on the DATE and ordered by TIME ASC, so the first record and the second record of the DATE are pairs, the third record and fourth record of the DATE are paired too. Please let me know if you need me to explain anything else. There will always be an even number of records per date.

Thanks

Comment: What is the logic here? Why are `7` and `8` mated with themselves?

Comment: Can you explain clearly? `MateID` is foreign key reference ?

Comment: Edited to explain more clearly

Comment: Your explanation and desired results are contradictory. Are the desired results for 7 and 8 an error?

Comment: Hi Martin my apologies, 7 and 8 was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and some simple maths to generate `PairID`s:

```
declare @Tab table (UID int not null,Date date not null,time time not null)
insert into @Tab (UID,Date,Time) values
(1,'20130607','08:00'),
(2,'20130607','10:00'),
(3,'20130607','13:00'),
(4,'20130607','17:00'),
(5,'20130608','07:00'),
(6,'20130608','11:00'),
(7,'20130608','14:00'),
(8,'20130608','18:00')

;With PairedRows as (
    select UID,Date,Time,
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date,Time) + 1) / 2 as PairID
    from @Tab
)
select p1.UID,p1.Date,p1.Time,p2.UID
from
    PairedRows p1
        inner join
    PairedRows p2
        on
            p1.PairID = p2.PairID and
            p1.UID != p2.UID
```

(I've done this as a `SELECT`, but it's easy enough to switch it to an `UPDATE` if this is meant to be a permanent pairing - it's not really clear from your question)

---

It may better match your model to `PARTITION BY Date` and only `ORDER BY Time` in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function - but since in this case you've stated that every date has an even number of rows, and all we care about are those rows which are assigned the same `PairID` without caring about the numeric value, it shouldn't affect the result of the query.

But it may better document your requirements.